# Android WebView iframe data url

Tags: android, html

Does Android WebView support data url in the iframe?

This code crashes my app:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = '<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+DQogICAgPGhlYWQ+PC9oZWFkPg0KICAgIDxib2R5Pg0KICAgIAlWSUNUT1JZIEhFWSBIRVkNCiAgICA8L2JvZHk+DQo8L2h0bWw+" id="my_iframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" onLoad="iFrameLoaded();"></iframe>';
```

The data decoded is:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        VICTORY HEY HEY
    </body>
</html>
```

Platform is:
Samsung Galaxy S2, 
Android version 2.3.5

UPDATE: I forgot to add that this works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't seem to be supported in Android WebView.

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace

Comment: I can't because my app runs into a third party container (basically a WebView with some JS+CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my tests tell me that it doesn't (for versions > 2.3.5 I dont' know)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JS enabled ?

```
webView.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is the Android Doc about WebViews

hope this help

Comment: Yes, JS is enabled (all other JS functions I have work fine).